# Ember-cli not proxying requests

Tags: ember.js, proxy, ember-cli

Version 0.0.40 of ember-cli is not proxying requests to my api backend when I run `ember server --proxy http://localhost:3000`.  The requests are just sent to `http://localhost:4200/model` with no error other than this endpoint not existing (which makes sense since this is not the url for my api which is versioned /api/v1).

Here's the contents of my application.js file:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had a typo in my directory structure that was causing this.  My adapters directory was spelled incorrectly:

`ember/app/adapaters/application.js`

and it should be

`ember/app/adapters/application.js`